# How to share Wifi through ethernet cable to windows pc?

Tags: wireless, networking, windows

I am right now using ubuntu 12.04 64bit, I have a small Ethernet net cable. I read somewhere that you can share your wifi from ubuntu to other pc by some editing in network settings.

Here is what I tried (http://blog.arvixe.com/how-to-share-wireless-connection-via-ethernet-cable-in-ubuntu-to-any-device/)

I tried it and it even showed the light beeping in both sides Btw my other PC has windows 7 64bit. and on there it just didn't connect. It just showed "Identifying..." and "no internet connections"

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me:

1. click on the network icon on the top right of the screen and click on `edit connections`
2. go into the `wired tab` and click on  `add`
3. Name it whatever you want, i normally name it `Share`
4. Go into the  `ipv4 settings` tab and select  `shared to other computers` in the "method" drop-down list.
5. Save the connection.
6. Now, making sure that you are connected through wireless network, connect both computers with the ethernet cable, then click on the network icon on the top right of the screen and select the  `Shared`  connection we just created (or whatever you named the connection). So at this moment you should be connected to both, your wireless connection through the wireless interface, and to the "Shared" connection we just created on the wired interface.

Comment: ok i'll try that and give u feedback :) thanks for quick reply :)

Comment: Thanksssssss it finally worked :D yay thank u thank thank u :)

Comment: No problem!!! im glad it worked!! would you mark the thread as solved please?

Comment: Just connects and disconnects, Ubuntu 14.04 to Raspberry Pi.